# Spring boot: RabbitMq and Database management when error occurred in Exchange

Tags: database, spring-boot, transactions, rabbitmq

I have a problem to manage the RabbitMQ and Database transaction **in case the exchange is not found**. This is the simple sequence:

1. Put message to Exchange
2. Mark as sent the sent message in database

When the Exchange is not found, the message is not sent, however the row is updated in database, which doesn't respect the transactional behavior.
Transaction are correctly managed for other error cases (DB error or RabbitMQ not available).

How can I manage this use case as transactional processing?

Transaction enabled in configuration:

```java
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingClass("org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager")
public RabbitTransactionManager rabbitTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new RabbitTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(jacksonMessageConverter());
    template.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return template;
}
```

My service:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void push(Message message) {

    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(
                "MessageExchange",
                "binding.key",
                objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message));

    repository.markAsSent(message.getId());
}
```

Error fired after leaving method, not in the `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` method :

```
[AMQP Connection] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory.log : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'MessageExchange' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
[ThreadPoolTaskScheduler1] ERROR o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion : TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed during transaction
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1171)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.txCommit(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll(RabbitResourceHolder.java:153)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceSynchronization.afterCompletion(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:332)
```